# Working and tested JSon serializers for .NET 4?

Tags: json, .net-4.0

Entire question is in the title: Are there any working, and tested, JSon serializer implementations for .NET 4?

I tried [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) on codeplex, but it is neither updated for .NET 4.0, nor does it handle culture differences (like comma/dot in floating point values).

Are there any that works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aren't the ones built-in the framework working in your scenario ([JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) and [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx))? Those are guaranteed to be working and tested.

Comment: *smack forehead* So they're built in now? :P

Comment: @Lasse, those classes have always been part of the core framework.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for my WCF4 REST service, and it works fine, so the `DataContractJsonSerializer` should work for you.

```
    public static string SerializeToJSON<T>(T obj)
    {
        string sRet = "";
        var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(memStream, obj);
            byte[] blob = memStream.ToArray();
            var encoding = new System.Text.UTF7Encoding();
            sRet = encoding.GetString(blob);
        }
        return sRet;
    }
```